# Implementing a form on a modal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, bootstrap-modal, thymeleaf

So, I have two htmls, one is a simple form, that create and edits registers, with a description and a id, and the other is for listing all the registers on my database.

My problem is that I'm trying to put both in one page, putting my form on a model, but the controller for this class redirect the URL when the methods on de form are in use (save, and edit).

I was told that using JavaScript may solve my problem, but I'm really beginning on this stuff, I don't know how to implemented. I'm trying to use thymeleaf, is case it is relevant.

If anyone could help, I appreciate.

P.S. English is not my native language, sorry if there is any typo or if its hard to understand

**Form:**

```
<form  method="post" th:action="${marca.id == null} ? @{/marcas/salvar} : @{/marcas/editar} " th:object="${marca}">
            <div class="form-row col-md-6">
                <!--<label for="id">Codigo</label>-->

                <label for="descricao">Descricao</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao" autofocus="autofocus"  placeholder="Marca"
                       th:field="*{descricao}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('descricao')} ? 'is-invalid'"/>

                <div class="invalid-feedback" >
                    <span th:errors="*{descricao}"></span>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Salvar</button>

        </form>
```

**List:**

```
<div class="container" id="listagem">
        <div th:replace="fragments/alert"></div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cod.</th>
                    <th>Descricao</th>
                    <th>Acao</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="m : ${marcas}">
                    <td th:text="${m.id}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${m.descricao}"></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" th:href="@{/marcas/editar/{id} (id=${m.id})}" role="button">
                        <span class="oi oi-pencil" title="Editar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" th:href="@{/marcas/excluir/{id} (id=${m.id})}" role="button" >
                            <span class="oi oi-circle-x" title="Excluir"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller** (In case it is needed)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/marcas")
public class MarcaController {
    @Autowired
    private MarcaService service;
    @GetMapping("/cadastrar")
    public String cadastrar(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("marca", new Marca());
        return "/marca/form";
    }
    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public String listar(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("marcas", service.buscarTodos());
        return "/marca/list";
    }
    @PostMapping("/salvar")
    public String salvar(@Valid Marca marca, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "/marca/form";
        }
        service.salvar(marca);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Marca inserida com sucesso!");
        return "redirect:/marcas/listar";
    }
    @GetMapping("/editar/{id}")
    public String preEditar(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("marca", service.buscarPorId(id));
        return "/marca/form";
    }
    @PostMapping("/editar")
    public String editar(@Valid Marca marca, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "/marca/form";
        }
        service.editar(marca);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Marca editada com sucesso!");
        return "redirect:/marcas/listar";
    }
    @GetMapping("/excluir/{id}")
    public String excluir(@PathVariable("id") Long id, RedirectAttributes attr) {
            service.excluir(id);
            attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Marca excluida com sucesso");
            return "redirect:/marcas/listar";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **Bootstrap** it is quite easy to achieve. All you have to do is set some tags for your buttons and your modals. Here is what you gotta do. Change your edit `<a>` for the following button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-target=${m.id}">Editar</button>
```

What we are doing in the last line of code, is dynamically setting our `data-target` using Thymeleaf dynamic attributes.

Now, all you need to do, is add your form inside the following `<div>`. This `<div>` is needed to be created for each post adn each one of them must have a different **id**, that is wahy we set them dynamically using Thymeleaf with `th:id`.

```
<div class="modal fade" th:id="${m.id}" role="dialog">
    <form  method="post" th:action="@{/marcas/editar}" th:object="${marca}">
     ...
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I put without any content on the div, it opens the page but don't open the modal, and when I fill the div with the form it doesn't even open the list page. Is a HTTP Status 500, something about the expression on the form th:action

Comment: Try it with the current change. I was just using the expression you added in your code.